# Changing URL without changing Actual Path to Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.Net and working on MVC 4. I want to replace my current URL with a customized URL.

For example: 
Current URL: http://www.testsite.com/home?pageId=1002

Desired URL: http://www.testsite.com/1002/home/

So the URL that is displayed in the address bar will be the desired one and actual URL working will be the current one.

I have tried URL routing in Global.asax file of my project but doesn't seems to be working for me.

What exactly I want is to put the URL Like this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 4 provide a toolbox way to write your application. The URL that you see in the browser comes from Routing that do the hard work to convert url to app routes and app routes to url.

1) The default ASP.NET MVC 4 Template project comes with a file at App_Start folder named RouteConfig, where you must config the routes for the app.

2) The routes has precedence order, so, put this route before the default one:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RouteForPageId",
            url: "{pageId}/{action}",
            //controller = "Home" and action = "Index" are the default value,
            //change for the Controller and action that you have
            //pageId is the parameter from the action that will return the page
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Now you can enter myappdomain/1220/index for exemple.

Hopes this help you! Take a look here for more info [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)!